# Is it possible to limit the number of tls sockets created (Android) when connecting to ESP32 https server?

Tags: java, android, ssl, esp32

We have the following setup:

- ESP32 starts a https server, with the limitation of 6 concurrent TCP socket connections
- A Xamarin App running on Android using javax.net.ssl as the TLS client

The observation is, that the App opens 6 sockets. Unfortunately we have memory limitations on the ESP32. About 160kb of heap is available and for each socket we need roughly 30kb for each SSL session context. Is it possible to limit the number of sockets created by the Android tls client?

To clarify, the app is delivered by a supplier.
For the communication the xamarin httpclient is used, which does not provide low level access to the sockets. Observing the network communication with wireshark it shows that the Client automatically used between 4-6 socket connects. This seems to be in line with the http protocol, to speed up the page loads. see for example

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s04.html

Comment: You programmed that Xamarin app. So why are you opening six connections? You should know that i think. For what are they opened?

Comment: I did not downvote. A browser will open several sockets if for instance the html page contains images. If the html source contains `<img>` tags. Then for every picture a new socket can be opened. You should know why your app opens more sockets then one. Also extra threads/sockets can be started to include scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my App but we can communicate with the Developer team that provides the App. Sure, it would be possible to ask them to implement the https client themselves and therefore limit the nr of socket connections but it could have been possible to set somewhere in Android that limitation. The lwip stack for example allows limiting the number of listening and active tcp connections (aka sockets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here in case someone else stumbles upon a similar requirement "to limit number of connections".

The HttpClientHandler has a Property MaxConnectionsPerServer, which sets a connection Limit per Endpoint.

The full documentation can be found [dotnet-maxconnections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.maxconnectionsperserver?view=net-7.0)